# The app references non-public symbols while using Compose Multiplatform module

Tags: ios, compose-multiplatform

I implemented the library which saves logs in the DB (via Realm) and displays them in iOS and Android by using Compose Multiplatform. I integrated it into the main project and it works fine. But the problem is that when I upload the IPA into App Store uploading lane fails with the following errors:

```
ERROR: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] Asset validation failed (11) The app references non-public symbols in Payload/AppName.app/AppName: _ubidi_close, _ubidi_getDirection, _ubidi_getLength, _ubidi_getLevelAt, _ubidi_openSized, _ubidi_reorderVisual, _ubidi_setPara, _ubrk_clone, _ubrk_current, _ubrk_first, _ubrk_getRuleStatus, _ubrk_next, _uloc_getDefault, _uloc_toLanguageTag, _uscript_getScript (ID: b685f704-5d49-42c6-b138-5d9237029ac2)
Error uploading '/var/folders/cs/h_xrcbtd2v7dg83vc9mwmqx00000gp/T/a5916cdb-e373-444c-a53b-2cc97d201362.ipa'.
```

The version of compose multiplatform I use is 1.5.3. Kotlin version is 1.9.10.

As I think, the issue is that SKIA uses this symbols, but I don't know how can it be fixed. Maybe u have some ideas. Thanks in advance for any help!